# How to display div rows into a single columns in grid structure in mobile viewport using css?

Tags: html, css

I want to display all rows & column data in a single column in mobile viewport using grid display. I have written some CSS but it's not working.

My code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .wrapper .first {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">c</div>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
    <div class="third">c</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For desktop, the view is something like, which is correct:

```
A B C
A B C
A B C
```

For mobile viewports, I want output something like:

```
A
A
A
B
B
B
C
C
C
```

Can anyone help me how can I achieve it in mobile viewports?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wrapper, then use the `order` property, changing the template columns to a single column

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .first {
    order: 1;
  }
  .second {
    order: 2;
  }
  .third {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="first">A</div>
  <div class="second">B</div>
  <div class="third">c</div>

  <div class="first">A</div>
  <div class="second">B</div>
  <div class="third">c</div>

  <div class="first">A</div>
  <div class="second">B</div>
  <div class="third">c</div>

</div>
```

You could achive the same thing using `nth-child`

```css
.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}


@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .main {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  }
  .main > div:nth-child(3n-2) {
    order: 1;
  }
  .main > div:nth-child(3n-1) {
    order: 2;
  }
  .main > div:nth-child(3n) {
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>c</div>

  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>c</div>

  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>c</div>

</div>
```

Comment: No, I can't remove the wrapper class because I am using a loop to iterate the wrapper div.

Comment: If you can't remove the wrapper then you can not achieve what you want, The wrapper will force the ABC grouping. What other purpose the wrapper serve? Is the loop generating the code or doing something else? This is information that should be in the question.